# How to read value from JSON array?

Tags: php, laravel

At my database i has column `items`, and in this coluln i has value:

`[{"id":588,"user_id":1,"item_id":801,"created_at":"2020-12-16T11:55:40.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-12-16T11:55:40.000000Z","item":{"id":801,"market_hash_name":"Blackshield Protodrone Armor","image":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcUmoBVWSV6fSuGu387sW1JmKwFDiamtJBJs1_baPjBH79S3q4iEhfnxJ4TCnmRE5MF0mNbN9J7yjRrnrkNqNjr7IICSIFVsaVzYr1O4kOq915O16pyfm3Bi6SVzt3nYnUC0n1gSOXdKDzqL","exterior":"Mythical","rarity":"Mythical","color":"D2D2D2","is_stattrak":0,"price":1.3,"created_at":null,"updated_at":"2020-12-16T19:45:02.000000Z"}}]`

I need to take value of `item_id`, i try to make it like:

```
<td>{{ $bet->items[item_id] }}</td>
```

But i received error: Use of undefined constant item_id - assumed 'item_id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

If try:

```
<td>{{ $bet->items['item_id'] }}</td>
```

I received: Illegal string offset 'item_id'

Or if try:

```
<td>{{ $bet->items["item_id"] }}</td>
```

I received same error: Illegal string offset 'item_id'

My full code at conttoller:

```
    $bets = Bet::query()->where('user_id', $user->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    foreach ($bets as $bet) {
        $profit += round($bet->win - $bet->bank, 2);
    }
```

At views:

```
@foreach($bets as $bet)
    <tr>
        <td>#{{ $bet->id }}</td>
        <td>#{{ $bet->game_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ round($bet->bank, 2) }} $</td>
        <td>{{ round($bet->win, 2) }} $</td>
        <td>{{ round($bet->multiplier, 2) }}x</td>
        <td>{{ round($bet->auto_withdraw, 2) }}x</td>
        <td>{{ $bet->items["item_id"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $bet->created_at }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: looks like $bet->items[0]->item_id

Comment: received `Trying to get property 'item_id' of non-object`

Comment: "_and in this coluln i has value ..._" That's a string, have you tried `json_decode()` to get its values?

Answer (score 2):

you have two option.
first :
turn your json into array and access it like this:

```
$items_array = json_decode($bet->items,true);
$item_id = $items_array[0]['item_id'];
```

second or you can do it like object:

```
$items_object = json_decode($bet->items);
$item_id = $items_array[0]->item_id;
```

Comment: if i make it, i can't use it in the foreach with `$bets`, right?

Answer (score 2):

if your column "item" is a string, you need to change it to json by using json_decode().

1.Array

```
$item_array = json_decode($item, true);  //if(second parameter is true), it will turn to array
$item_id = $items_array[0]['item_id'];  //then your item_id is
```

2.Object

```
$item_object = json_decode($item);  //if(second parameter is false), it will turn to object
$item_id = $items_array[0]->item_id;  //then your item_id is
```